# Current sink - power and heat calculation

Tags: mosfet

My goal is to build a constant current sink to profile different batteries. The maximum paramters are

Vin=4.2V
Isink = 1A

Resulting in a maximum power of 4.2W

The circuit is equivalent with the following:
[image: Image of Circuit]

To select a suitable mosfet i would have to know

1.) How much will the mosfet heat up

2.) What type of heatspreader / cooler would be suitable to cool a common type mosfet (TO-220)

3.) Are there any mosfet that can operate at the given parameters without a cooling device!

Comment: Calculate the voltage drop across the MOSFET and multiply that yb the current, which is either 1A (your spec) or 4.2A from that schematic under the specified conditions. You'll need to know what V+ and RL are : you didn't say.  2) Calculatethe thermal resistance you need in degrees/watt from (1) and choose a suitable one from a catalog. 3) probably not.

Comment: V+ would be 4.2V in my case, and Rload is 0

Comment: @sgt_johnny Typo in your last comment. Rload=0? || As shown at full drive Rload = 4.2A less a smidgeon due to FET Rdson.

Comment: Load needs be no smaller than 2.5Ohms. This gives you 1 A at VBat = 2.5V (abs abs lowest you ever ever should go.) Really 3 Ohm and 3V at 1A is about as low as most would need.  2.5 Ohms gives P_FET_max of 1.76W at 840 mA with 4.2V battery.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the device should be for different battery, for example also LiMnO2, which can below 2V.  the Current is regualated by DAC and by formular "Iout = VIN/1R".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any power mosfet will do. For example if you pick IRF3205 you need find this datasheet information:

[image]

The worst case scenario is shorted battery so all 4.2W will be on mosfet. You can look at the wattage like on "current source". So through your thermal circuit consisting of thermal resistance will flow 4.2W of power. You have to have in mid that the all temperatures are calculated respect to the ambient temperature(showed as the voltage source). In general you want the lowest possible temperature on your junction (chip inside the transistor) so therefore you need create "short circuit" for "power current" (4.2W).

[image]

If you want operate without heatsink you need to find junction_to_ambient thermal resistance in datasheet. Then the temperature on junction will be:
(junction_to_ambient * wattage) + ambient_temperature
(62 * 4.2) + 25 = 285.4 °C

As you can see this is much higher as allowed from datasheet (175°C). So if you want lower the temperature you need to lower thermal resistance case_to_ambient by adding the heatsink. When you add heatsink you replace case_to_ambient thermal resistance with two new thermal resistances case_to_sink and sink_to_ambient. You can find heatsink thermal resistance in it's datasheet. It is not constant but it varies with dissipated wattage. I will pick for our example 10 °C/W. The case_to_sink thermal resistance is usually 0.5 °C/W or even less if you use thermal paste. So now you have new thermal circuit:
[image]

And temperature of junction will be:
((0.75 + 0.5 + 10) * 4.2) + 25 = 72.25 °C
You can also calculate temperature on heatsink:
( 10 * 4.2) + 25 = 67 °C
And you can also calculate it back so if you want maximum temperature on heatsink 60°C then you need thermal resistance of heatsink:
((60 - 25) / 4.2) - 0.5 - 0.75 = 7.08333 °C/W

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: Worst case is NOT full on as Vds ~= 0. Worst case (ref max power transfer theorum) is when Rds_FET = Rload . Use load = 4.2 Ohms as he says 1max = 1A (but he may need lower R as battery V will of course fall).Say 4 Ohms for simplicity.  At Rfet = 4 Ohms I at 4.2V = 0.% A and Pdis FET = I^2 R = 0.25*4 = 1 Watt.

Comment: @Russell McMahon You are wrong, worst case is 4.2W on transistor when you connect shorted battery. Max power transfer theorum applies on voltage source and it's internal resistance, but this is sink current source. And even if it was voltage source it still wouln't be true.

Comment: @andz Sometimes :-) | It deep-ends what you mean by "shorted battery. OP says 1A max. If you are going to connect the battery to ground "things could get interesting". As posed he indicates it suggests a load able to sink 1A max. This could be far lower than the minimum necessary with eg PWM but he has not suggested that. Realistically a 2.5 Ohm resistor is lowest R needed allowing 1A at 2.5V. | PFET is then 1.76W at 4.2V at 840 mA (max power transfer) and 1.7W at 1A at 4.2V. || I'd personally aim at PWM and no heatsink.

Answer (score 1):

((100-efficiency) /100) * current * voltage = Watts of heat dissipation

example : 0.20 (80% efficiency) * 3 volts * 2 Amps = 1.2W heat output

Small heatsink should do around 25mm. You may be able to get away with something smaller too[image]

Comment: Where does efficiency comes from?

Comment: @sgt_johnny From the data sheet, look at the efficiency graph

Comment: The datasheet of what?

Comment: @Transistor The datasheet of the MOSFET will have either a graph showing loss of energy at different power levels ,or values inputted into a table. From there you can calculate the power loss. E.g. 3V 1A in to mosfet and 3V 0.8A out. 0.2A is heat, so efficiency of 80%. 0.2A * V = 0.6W total heat dissipation.

Comment: How do you get 1 A into a MOSFET and only 0.8 A out? Where does the other 0.2 A go to?

Answer (score 1):

Mosfet TO220 in free air will rise 60 C when dissipating 0.5W and 125 C at 1W. There is no device for 4.2W , you need a heatsink. The data of a heatsink tells the temperature rise per W , a heatsink of 10 C/W will heat to 42 C above ambient.

Comment: Tip: SE supports HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments).